# How to use MorfologikAnalyzer in apache lucene for lemmatization?

Tags: apache, lucene

I am creating an English search engine using Apache Lucene. Since I need to do the lemmatization for that, I am using *Stanford CoreNLP* and I know how to do that.

Is it possible to use *MorfologikAnalyzer* or something similar from the out of the box Apache Lucene to do the lemmatization?

Comment: Morfologik analyzer is for Polish language, right?

Comment: Yes.it a dictionary-driven lemmatization filter and analyzer

Comment: But you mentioned English search engine/

Comment: English search engine means i am creating search engine using English language.so to get the lemma of a word can i use Morfologik analyzer in apache lucene.if not is there any way  get lemma of a word using apache lucene rather using Stanford-corenlp thats what i asked

Comment: Yeah, but Morfologik is intended to be used for Polish, how you suppose to use it for English? overall, there are no built in lemmatizers in Lucene

Comment: yeah, that's why i used  Stanford-corenlp lib for do the lemmatization. I thought there is a lib in lucene to do the lemmatizaiton.

Comment: Sorry, I only now understands the question. Do you mind replying it and also editing the question a bit to be easier understandable for the future use/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, *MorfologikAnalyzer* is only suppose to work with Polish language and provide stemming capabilities, rather than lemmatization.

There are no built-in Apache Lucene analyzers that might help you. So, the existing options for you are the following:

- [Stanford CoreNLP](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/simple.html)
- [OpenNLP lemmatizer](https://opennlp.apache.org/docs/1.8.0/apidocs/opennlp-tools/opennlp/tools/lemmatizer/Lemmatizer.html)
- [NLTK Lemmatizer](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/stem/wordnet.html) (Python)

Of course there are several paid lemmatization engines, some of them may be could be even more rich than those above, especially if lemmatization is required for the specific domain - publishing, etc.

I wouldn’t list any of them here, but it shouldn’t be hard to find them if needed.